# Is it possible to update a row of data using position of column (e.g. like a list index) in Python / SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to compare two rows of data to one another which I have stored in a list.

```
for x in range(0, len_data_row):
    if company_data[0][0][x] == company_data[1][0][x]:
        print ('MATCH 1: {} - {}'.format(x, company_data[0][0][x]))
        # do nothing

    if company_data[0][0][x] == None and company_data[1][0][x] != None:
        print ('MATCH 2: {} - {}'.format(x, company_data[1][0][x]))
        # update first company_id with data from 2nd


    if company_data[0][0][x] != None and company_data[1][0][x] == None:
        print ('MATCH 3: {} - {}'.format(x, company_data[0][0][x]))
        # update second company_id with data from 1st
```

Psuedocode of what I want to do:

If data at index[x] of a list is not None for row 2, but is blank for row 1, then write the value of row 2 at index[x] for row 1 data in my database.

The part I can't figure out is if in SQLAlchemy you can do specify which column is being updated by an "index" (I think in db-land index means something different than what I mean. What I mean is like a list index, e.g., list[1]). And also if you can dynamically specify which column is being updated by passing a variable to the update code? Here's what I'm looking to do (it doesn't work of course):

```
def some_name(column_by_index, column_value):
    u = table_name.update().where(table_name.c.id==row_id).values(column_by_index=column_value)
    db.execute(u)
```

Thank you!